# LookupSPListItemId and Person field in SharePoint 2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio

I'm trying to use the `LookupSPListItemId` activity in a SharePoint 2013 workflow in Visual Studio. The condition I'm trying to set is when a person field equals a specific person.

The problem is I'm not sure what the format of the person parameter should be (which needs to be a string according to Visual Studio)

I have tried the user's ID (i.e. 2 as a string).
I have tried the user's login ID (i.e. domain\username)
I have tried the user's name (i.e. Joe Bloggs)
I have tried the user's claims login

When debugging with Visual Studio I can see in the workflow debugger output window an error occurs, presumably because I'm not passing in the correct parameter in the correct format.

This is the error I am seeing:

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 02/01/2015 17:18. Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to `http://server/sites/sc3/leave/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'ebac8268-e9be-4cde-9573-ae242333f5bd')/Items?%24filter=PersonId+eq+'2'&%24select=ID%2CID` Correlation Id: e649d849-9499-a1bc-9412-93930eb5f845 Instance Id: 98f7ec21-4381-4e9d-be20-1c094e02fff6

Comment: Why can't you use the users email? I believe the email will be unique.

Comment: @AmalHashim are you sure I am able to use an email address as input into a filter for a Person field?

Comment: Submits: I was just throwing out ideas. I haven't got chance to use `LookupSPListItemId` so far. From your error message, it seems the `PersonId` you are comparing is with `2`. Also the request is not valid because at the end there is an extra `%2CID`. Try to put the URL into browser and check if it works.

Comment: Amal, thanks for the tip re putting the URL into a browser. The response was clearly telling me the field name was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, this is what I was seeing in the response XML:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
Column 'PersonId' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. /sites/sc3/leave/Lists/Leave
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

It seems when using the `LookupSPListItemId` activity and selecting a field of type Person/Group to filter on, Visual Studio decided to put "Id" at the end of the column name.

I.e. my Person/Group column name was "Person", but Visual Studio was setting it to "PersonId". I renamed it back to "Person" and the workflow no longer was throwing errors. I mark this down to another of many quirks of SharePoint/Visual Studio.