# How to find listItem by Person column in Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a Custom list with column "User" of type "Person or Group".

I want to find list item by ID of a user. When I trying to use LookupSPListItemID Workflow returns me a message

> Column "UserId" does not exist. It may have been deleted by another
>   user.

1. Why suffix "Id" is added to request?
2. How to find list item by id of a user

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer on this post, if you remove the "ID" that was appended by Visual Studio to your Column, that should resolve your problem.   [LookupSPListItemId and Person field in SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126462/lookupsplistitemid-and-person-field-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot understand where I should remove "ID"

Comment: Here is a good tutorial. Look at bullet #28. Verify the PropertyName and PropertyValue.

Comment: Sorry, but what does  "bullet #28" mean?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the tutorial. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/845039/lookupsplist-lookupsplistitem-lookupsplistitemid-activitie/